# How to get Standard Deviation of a single number in C#

Tags: math, c#-4.0

How to calculate standard deviation of a single decimal value, in C#

I do it in SAS code as the following:

```
std(x y m ) = xSTD YSTD mSDT;
```

Comment: what do you mean by SD of a single number?

Comment: This isn't physically possible, or at least lacks a purpose. A standard deviation only applies to a collection of numbers.

Answer (score 8):

It is simply 0 see the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

1. Let X be the number
2. Calculate EV of [x] which is x
3. Subtract EV from each element in set which is [0]
4. Take the average of [0] which is 0
5. Take the square root of 0 which is 0